# If condition true for loop other rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I should check if status is 'Yes' in column 'Bad_loan', if true, check other names in 'client_name', if client has another loans set value 'Yes' for all his loans

```
def bad_loan(df):
    for row in df:
        status = row['bad_loan']
        name = row['name_client']
        if status == 'Yes':
            for n in df:
                name_client = df['name_client']
                if name == name_client:
                    df['bad_loan'] = 'Yes'
                else:
                    df['bad_loan'] = 'No'

bad_loan(df)
```

it returns TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Welcome to SO. provide a sample dataframe with expected output. use this as a guide : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples. It is quite possible that there is a vectorized solution to ur problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in df:
```

You can't iterate this way with pandas

Try iloc like this

```
def bad_loan(df):
    for i in range(len(df)):
        row = df.iloc[i]
        status = row['bad_loan']
        name = row['name_client']
        if status == 'Yes':
            for n in df:
                name_client = df['name_client']
                if name == name_client:
                    df['bad_loan'] = 'Yes'
                else:
                    df['bad_loan'] = 'No'

bad_loan(df)
```

Comment: I tried it, and result                                                                                                    
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: probably you have NaN values inyour csv. Try adding "df.fillna(0)" before your for  loop. (Chance 0 to whatever value you want)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#make a list of all the names with bad loans:

names = df[df["bad_loan"]=="Yes"]["name_client"]

#set bad loan to yes if name in list

df["bad_loan"] = np.where(df["name_client"].isin(names),"Yes","No")
```